# Password reset confirm page not loading

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am building the reset password page, the first page where the users enter his email work fine, he receive the reset password email with success. The problem it with the page where the user actually write his new password.

When I click on the link / go to the page it give me this error:

`assert uidb64 is not None and token is not None  # checked by URLconf`

I am following this docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/views/

here is my views.py

```
@sensitive_post_parameters()
@never_cache
def password_reset_confirm(request, uidb64=None, token=None,
                           template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html',
                           token_generator=default_token_generator,
                           set_password_form=SetPasswordForm,
                           post_reset_redirect=None,
                           current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    """
    View that checks the hash in a password reset link and presents a
    form for entering a new password.
    """
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    assert uidb64 is not None and token is not None  # checked by URLconf
    if post_reset_redirect is None:
        post_reset_redirect = reverse('password_reset_complete')
    else:
        post_reset_redirect = resolve_url(post_reset_redirect)
    try:
        # urlsafe_base64_decode() decodes to bytestring on Python 3
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, UserModel.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and token_generator.check_token(user, token):
        validlink = True
        title = ('Enter new password')
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = set_password_form(user, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(post_reset_redirect)
        else:
            form = set_password_form(user)
    else:
        validlink = False
        form = None
        title = ('Password reset unsuccessful')
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'title': title,
        'validlink': validlink,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)

    if current_app is not None:
        request.current_app = current_app

    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context)
```

here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('password_reset/', views.password_reset, name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', views.password_reset_done, name="password_reset_done"),
    path('reset/MTU/set-password/', views.password_reset_confirm, name="password_reset_confirm")
]
```

Comment: Your `password_reset_confirm` path in your urls doesn't include `uidb64` or `token` parameters, see the example in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views

Comment: I tried ```path('reset/MTU/set-password/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.password_reset_confirm, name="password_reset_confirm")``` and it not working. Also im not sure if it the right solution because as you can see on doc I pointed above, in the ```def password_reset_confirm()``` function uidb64 and token are set to None.